# Extension of $C^k$ functions: lower bounds

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider  $f\in C^k(U)$ for an bounded open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, such that $0<A\leq|D f|\leq B$ on $U$, and suppose that $U^\prime$ is a smooth bounded open whose closure is within in $U$.

Is it possible to extend $f$ from $U^\prime$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$ so that the extension $g\in C^k(\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfies $g=f$ on $U^\prime$ and $0<\alpha\leq |Dg|\leq \beta$ everywhere (for some $0<\alpha\leq A$,$\infty> \beta\geq B$)?

The upper bound is not a problem, we can just extend $f$ with Withney's Theorem and chop it off at some point, but what about the lower bound?

---

As pointed out by Vladimir in the comments, the answer is clearly no without further assumption on $U$ : so let us assume $U$ is smooth and convex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample: $U=\{1<|x|<4\}\subset R^2$, $U'=\{2<|x|<3\}$, $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: Yes, the Hairy Ball Theorem, thanks. What if $U^\prime$ is simply connected?

Comment: Counterexample: $U=\{1<|x|<4\}\subset R^3$, $U'=\{2<|x|<3\}$, $f(x)=|x|$. If $U'$ is *contractible*, the answer might be yes, but I do not know yet. In fact, maybe try the case in which $U'$ is a ball first?

Comment: OK, no hard feelings:)